# Weird Behaviour in iOS Safari with Different Languages in the Same String

Tags: html, ios, css, character-encoding

I have a really strange behaviour in Safari. The problem is that I have a string (inside an  tag) which has one part of it written in cyrillic (Bulgarian) and the other part written in latin (English).

On all the desktop browsers I have, it's all working good and there are no problems at all. Then I took my iPhone, and I noticed a surprise: part of the sentence is bold (as it should be according to the CSS), and part is normal.

You can see this weird behaviour here:
http://www.buderus-bg.com/bultherm/product/10

What can it be? And why I get this problem only on iOS?
The charset of the website UTF-8. And that field in the database is a utf8_general_ci.

[image: A screenshot taken from an iPhone 6]

Comment: Please include sufficient code (HTML, CSS, and text content) for reproducing the issue *in the question itself*. Also please describe how you inferred that some text is bold and some other text is normal—visual impression can be deceptive, since some fonts look bolder than others (when regular typeface is used for both).

Comment: You can grab an iPhone if you have one and you can see the problem yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to display the text using a font that doesn't contain Cyrillic characters (Google's Open Sans with `subset=latin`), so the browser will need to find a different font to display the Cyrillic text.

Solution: remove the `subset=latin` bit.

Edit: the fact that it happens only in iOS with Safari is a coincidence. The browser searches for a font that can display the Cyrillic characters, and what it finds is sufficiently different from Open Sans that you can see the difference in thickness. On my desktop machine, I see the difference too.

Comment: Stupid me! You're totally right! What I did, though is: subset=latin,cyrillic

Comment: You're welcome. And thanks for the comment; up to now I hadn't realised that you could put multiple subsets in the Google font definition!